# How to insert a DropDownList inside the GridView's first header

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I have a GridView where I have some data and also another HTML table right above with the DropDownList to filter the GridView. The only issue is, because they are two separate tables, the column doesn't match up. To make up for that, inside the RowCreated method I added the following as an example:

```
protected void yourTasksGV_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        GridView hGrid = (GridView)sender;
        GridViewRow gvrRow = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert);
        TableHeaderCell tcCell = new TableHeaderCell();
        tcCell.Text = @"<asp:DropDownList ID='ddlTaskName2' CssClass='chosen-select' DataSourceID='dsPopulateTaskName2' AutoPostBack='true' DataValueField='Task Name' runat='server' Width='100%' Font-Size='11px' AppendDataBoundItems='true' OnSelectedIndexChanged='ddlTaskName_onSelectIndexChanged'>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text='All' Value='%'></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                <asp:SqlDataSource ID='sPopulateTaskName2' runat='server' ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:gvConnString %>' SelectCommand=\""SELECT [actionname] from [OnBase].[hsi].[action]\""></asp:SqlDataSource>";
        tcCell.ColumnSpan = 1;
        gvrRow.Cells.Add(tcCell);

        TableHeaderCell tcCell2 = new TableHeaderCell();
        tcCell2.Text = "TEST #2";
        tcCell2.ColumnSpan = 1;
        gvrRow.Cells.Add(tcCell2);


        yourTasksGV.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, gvrRow);
    }
}
```

I don't see any DropDownList when the GridView is created.

My table that I am using for filtering is this:

```
<table class="taskGridView" runat="server">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTaskName" CssClass="chosen-select" DataSourceID="dsPopulateTaskName" AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Task Name" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="11px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTaskName_onSelectIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulateTaskName" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gvConnString %>" SelectCommand=""></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlService" CssClass="chosen-select" DataSourceID="dsPopulateService" AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Service" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="11px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlService_onSelectIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulateService" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gvConnString %>" SelectCommand=""></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" CssClass="chosen-select" DataSourceID="dsPopulateStatus" AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Status" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="11px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlStatus_onSelectIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulateStatus" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gvConnString %>" SelectCommand=""></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDueDate" CssClass="chosen-select" DataSourceID="dsPopulateDueDate" AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Due Date" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="11px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlDueDate_onSelectIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulateDueDate" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gvConnString %>" SelectCommand=""></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOwner" CssClass="chosen-select" DataSourceID="dsPopulateOwner" AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Owner" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="11px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlOwner_onSelectIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulateOwner" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gvConnString %>" SelectCommand=""></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlClient" CssClass="chosen-select" DataSourceID="dsPopulateClient" AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Client" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="11px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlClient_onSelectIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulateClient" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gvConnString %>" SelectCommand=""></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSite" CssClass="chosen-select" DataSourceID="dsPopulateSite" AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Site" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="11px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSite_onSelectIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulateSite" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gvConnString %>" SelectCommand=""></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPractice" CssClass="chosen-select" DataSourceID="dsPopulatePractice" AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Practice" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="11px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPractice_onSelectIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulatePractice" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gvConnString %>" SelectCommand=""></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProvider" CssClass="chosen-select" DataSourceID="dsPopulateProvider" AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Provider" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="11px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlProvider_onSelectIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulateProvider" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gvConnString %>" SelectCommand=""></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am populating the SelectCommand from code-behind on Page_Load. I am also calling another function on Page_Load which references the DropDownList but I get a `The name 'DropDownList ID' does not exist in current content`

My GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="false" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#EBE9E9" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSorting="yourTasksGV_Sorting" AllowSorting="true" ID="yourTasksGV" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" EmptyDataText="You currently have no tasks assigned to you" OnRowDataBound="yourTasksGV_RowDataBound" OnRowCreated="yourTasksGV_RowCreated">
    <Columns>
        <asp:HyperLinkField Target="_self" DataNavigateUrlFields="Task Detail" DataTextField="Task Name" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="" HeaderText="Task Detail" SortExpression="Task Name" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Service" HeaderText="Service" SortExpression="Service" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Due Date" HeaderText="Due" SortExpression="Due Date" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Owner" HeaderText="Owner" SortExpression="Owner" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Client" HeaderText="Client" SortExpression="Client" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Site" HeaderText="Site" SortExpression="Site" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Practice" HeaderText="Practice" SortExpression="Practice" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Provider" HeaderText="Provider" SortExpression="Provider" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

What I want to do is take the DropDownList table and insert it inside the GridView HEADER right above the Header that is being generated.

As you can see in the below image the empty header where the DropDownList is supposed to go is there but I don't see anything. That's where I would like to put the DropDownList with the `all` option.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than adding markup to the cell text, which won't be evaluated correctly in the page lifecycle in the same way as if you had declared it in the aspx source, add controls to the `Controls` collection of an existing control.

For example,

```
DropDownList ddlTaskName2 = new DropDownList();
tcCell.Controls.Add(ddlTaskName2);
```

This should enable you to solve the problem of the dropdown not appearing as you have shown like this:

[image]

Below is a minimal working example you can use, that adds a dropdown to a GridView header cell.

Markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="GridViewHeaderControl.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="WebApplication7_JQuery.GridViewHeaderControl" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvMain" OnRowCreated="gvMain_RowCreated" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code-behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            gvMain.DataSource = new List<object> { new { ID = 1, Name = "First" }, new { ID = 2, Name = "Second" } };
            gvMain.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void gvMain_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            GridView hGrid = (GridView)sender;
            GridViewRow gvrRow = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert);

            DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
            ddl.Items.Add("Option 1");

            TableHeaderCell tcCell = new TableHeaderCell();
            tcCell.Controls.Add(ddl);
            gvrRow.Cells.Add(tcCell);
            gvMain.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, gvrRow);
        }            
    }
```

Set further properties of the dropdown as desired, per the markup that was loaded as cell text in your question.

You may need to explicitly code `ddl.DataBind()` after setting your datasourceid, depending on when you do other binding.

Here the ddl is dynamically created; however, you may wish to declare it in your markup instead so it gets a design-time variable you can reference anywhere in your code-behind for binding and other purposes:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvMain" OnRowCreated="gvMain_RowCreated" />
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlTaskName" />
```

and

```
tcCell.Controls.Add(ddlTaskName);
```

Comment: So keep the table as is and then add the controls? Confused.

Comment: @SiKni8 I've edited my answer to add a minimal working example you can use.

Comment: I will make some changes and see what I can do :) Thank you.

Comment: Question for you (`ddl = ddlTaskName`), If I am using this line (`ddlTaskName.SelectedIndex > 0`) in my Page_Load event which is now giving me an error: `The name 'ddlTaskName' does not exist in the current context` because I am actually creating it in my `RowCreated` function, how can I solve it? I think once that is working I should be good to go. Thank you

Comment: Actually Thanks to you I am able to put the DropDownList inside the GridView, now to bind it together :/ Here is the PAGE_LOAD event and the PullData function which binds the DropDownList and populates the GridView (https://www.diffchecker.com/id0oc0j2). If you can please tell me how to populate the DropDownList created inside the RowCreated and also how to reference the DDL from the PullData function, I am golden! :)

Comment: When I debug the code, `src` does show the correct query but the DropDownList doesn't populate :/

Comment: @SiKni8 I've expanded my example to show how you can access the ddl from anywhere in your code-behind to populate/bind it or check its selectedindex etc.

Comment: I updated my code with the exception of the Page_Load even which is binding the GridView (I am using `PullData` function) but everything else I was able to do but I am not getting it. Sorry :/

Comment: Actually the `src` is being in the DropDownList as a string, so each entry is a letter from the string :/ false alert

Comment: Thanks for the update. When you said markup, you mean in ASP.net like you showed? I can place that markup anywhere and the code-behind will attach it to the GridView I am guessing?

Comment: How do I give you 200 points? LOL... Thank YOU! The last bit of code you provided did the trick!!! THANK YOU THANK YOU!!! Seems like I did all the work already just needed the last bit!

Comment: I am wondering if you can also assist me with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27162698/how-to-cascade-dropdowns-from-left-to-right-and-right-to-left-in-a-sharepoint-we  Thanks :)